# Internet Usage on Samsung Galaxy Ace 5830.

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, data-monitoring

My provider gives my 3GB of data and I don't know how to find out how much I have used or have left.  Where can I find this information

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using a Galaxy Ace with Android v2.3 (Gingerbread), I suggest you to use an application like [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog&hl=en) or [Onavo Count](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid&feature=related_apps). But if you are using a Android phone with Android v4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or higher there is a built-in option in settings menu called "Data Usage".

Comment: Data usage was there in 2.2 as well, are you sure its not there in 2.3 ? Moreover these are not really reliable, it will even account your wi fi usage. Best way is to check with service provider, am sure they have a USSD code or something.

Answer (score 0):

3G Watchdog keeps separate totals for Wi-Fi and 3G data use, so there should be no confusion about whether it is from the mobile network allowance (3G data) or some wi-fi hotspot.  The watchdog can also be set to disable your 3G connection at some level (eg 80%) before you hit your limit.

AVG (antivirus) now includes a data usage monitor, but just warns and does not disable, as far as I know.  If I had a limit, I'd prefer to have the connection broken in case I started a high traffic application (eg world wide webcam) and might be charged for traffic above my allowance (network I used in 2012 charged around 100 GBP / US$ 150 per extra GB of data, something to avoid!).